# If hover then wait, else continue

Tags: jquery

I use jquery 1.3.2.  I try to write simple jquery to the ajax cart implemented on my website.
There are functions `ajaxCartOpenCart()` - opens cart block (simply unhides it) and `ajaxCartCloseCart()`.

I added simple code that after adding to the cart, unhides cart block, waits for 4 seconds and closes cart block.

```
ajaxCartOpenCart();
setTimeout(function() {
  ajaxCartCloseCart()
}, 4000);
```

The problem: I need to create a condition that says - if during this time of 4 sec. a mouse enters `#cart-block`, then don't close it and wait until mouse leaves. Else count 4 sec and close cart.

Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can clear the timeout and then call the ajax function when the mouse leaves. Something like:

```
var t = setTimeout(function () {
   // ...
}, 4000);

$('element').hover(function () {
  clearTimeout(t);
}, function () {
  ajaxCartCloseCart();
});
```

Comment: hello, this code works. Is it possible to use .live for the 'element'? It is recreated by ajax and breaks the jquery

Comment: You'll want to attach the hover event when you create the element.  Also, the `live` function is now deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I created something similar to this using `setInterval` to show and hide a top bar

demo jsfiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/frictionless/QmLAv/

```
$(function() {

   var showTime = 5000;
   var transition = 'slow';
   var target = $('.headerbar');
   var flag = false;

    target.slideDown(transition);
    var id = setInterval(function(){hide(target);}, showTime);

    var hide = function(item) {
        debugger;
        if(flag){
            return;
        }
        clearInterval(id);
        item.slideUp(transition);
    };

    target.hover(function() {
        flag = true;
        clearInterval(id);
        $(this).show();
    }, function() {
        flag = false;
        id = setInterval(function(){hide(target);}, showTime);
    });

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to control hide/show shop cart as below.
I think it's the simplest way, because you don't need to care about setTimeout and setInterval, which may cause unexpected result.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .shopCart .shopCartDetail
    {
        border: 1px solid;
        width: 100px;
        display: none;
    }
    .shopCart:hover .shopCartDetail
    {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
<div class="shopCart">
    Shop Cart
    <div class="shopCartDetail">
        This is Shop Cart Detail</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.shopCart').hover(function () {
        //Ajax update content
    });
</script>
```